# How to delete Account History details

Tags: delete, accounthistory

I would like to know as to how do we delete certain rows from the Account History details.

I had tried using the Data loader but there is no way to export or delete the account history ?

Comment: If you don't want anyone to see any Account History on any record using that layout, you can remove the related list from the page layout.

Answer (score 3):

Account History can be deleted in Salesforce after Spring '18 release. [Delete Field History and Field Audit Trail Data](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_api_data_services_fieldaudittrail.htm)

There is one posted issue [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210984/accounthistory-not-deleting-immediately-after-an-update)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete the account history.

You can:

1. Delete the account (thus deleting the history)
2. Recreate the account
3. Done no history...